# How can SwiftUI animations be isolated to child views?

Tags: animation, gridview, swiftui

I'm trying to animate a transformation within a cell of a grid view, but I don't want this animation to affect the layout of the cells as they are repositioned by data changes. I feel like this should be simple to do, but it doesn't work no matter what I try.

Perhaps someone can demonstrate SwiftUI where cells in a grid view can reorder themselves without a spring animation while the cells use a spring animation to resize locally? That would be greatly appreciated!

```
var body: some View {
  LazyVGrid(columns) {
    ForEach(dataSource.dataList) { // This is an array of structs
      CellView(data: $0)
    }
  }
  .animation(.default)
}


struct CellView: View {
  let data: CellData
  @State var contentScale: CGFloat = 1

  init(data: CellData) {
    self.data = data
    let anim = Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 50, damping: 5)
    withAnimation(anim) {
        self.contentScale = calcScaleFrom(data: data)
    }
  }

  var body: some View {
     // Configure cell with data
     // and animate scale based on data properties
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have a modifier on your Grid or somewhere with .animation(). This adds animation to all events affecting the component. Instead, remove that modifier, and use withAnimation{} around the action that causes the animation.

Comment: @nicksarno Great idea! I'm still learning animation with SwiftUI but that sounds like it will work!

Comment: If you're interested, I have a video on YouTube explaining this :) https://youtu.be/0WY-wrW2_bs

Comment: Alright, I understand your tutorial, but I'm still struggling to find a way to use withAnimation for a state that will be recreated each time my cells are "reconstructed" by the body of the grid view... ForEach(dataList) { CellView(data: $0) }

Comment: Essentially I want one animation to be used when the data list changes, and one animation to be used when the property of an element in the data list changes... :T

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: @nicksarno Yes, I have added some code to summarize the situation. I suspect I might need to change the CellData model somehow.

Comment: Sorry man I can't really tell what you're trying to do from that code. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't find the answer to my exact question... but I did find a workaround. My precise aim was making my cells update their *content* with a spring animation, but making the grid reorder the cell with the default animation. To do this I simply added a `withAnimation` block in my grid's data model code which selects the style of animation based on whether the data list changed order!

```
    @Published var currentList: [CellData]

    func updateData() {
      let newList = ...
      let anim: Animation
      if newList.map({$0.id}).elementsEqual(currentList.map({$0.id})) {
        // Data may have changed but does not require any cell reordering
        anim = Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 80, damping: 5)
      } else {
        // Cells will change order!
        anim = .default
      }
      withAnimation(anim) {
        currentList = newList
      }
    }
```